# Closing an activity after a number of second

Tags: android

After pushing a button, i want to close an activity. But, I’d like to wait some seconds before closing it, because users have to read a short message displayed on that activity.
I tried using Thread inside the onClick event

```
try{
  Thread.sleep(2000);
      finish();  
   }
  catch(Exception e){}
```

But, when I push the button, the entire objects are freeze (for example, the button stay pushed).

Then I used a simple Timer

```
timer.schedule(task(), 2000);
```

And it seems to work well. Is it correct to use a Timer in this situation, or should I use a Thread or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Activity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 2000) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to use a Handler

```
private Handler h = new Handler();

...

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
}, 2000);
```